# JavaFx WebView Window.print does not work

Tags: javascript, javafx, webview

I am trying to integrate the JavaFx WebView into a Swing application. I am through with the implementation and am finally stuck on just one last missing piece. As part of the requirement, we do need the ability to print certain content. The content is all existing third party html / site and all works fine, except for the embedded print button on the pages. The Print button calls the window.print() and somehow that does not work and am unable to print. This is a needed feature for us and am out of ideas and need some help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My web engine initialization is as follows:

```
    Runnable r = () ->
    {
        WebView view = new WebView();
        m_WebEngine = view.getEngine();
        //view.setContextMenuEnabled(false);

        getWebEngine().setOnStatusChanged(getStatusHandler());

        getWebEngine().getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(getProgressListener());

        getWebEngine().getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener(getErrorListener());

        getWebEngine().titleProperty().addListener(getTitleListener());

        getWebEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(getStatusListener());

        getWebEngine().setOnAlert(event -> showAlert(event.getData()));
        getWebEngine().setConfirmHandler(message -> showConfirm(message));

        getWebEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        getJfxPanel().setScene(new Scene(view));
    };

    Platform.runLater(r);
```

I tried with alert, popup, prompt and all other handlers and just doesn't work.

Any help on handling this properly would be greatly appreciated.